# Spring Boot Secure sample stacktrace

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I just pulled down the Spring Boot GIT project, ran an `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in the spring-boot-sample-secure folder, and imported just that project into STS.  However, when I run it, I get the following:

```
2013-11-06 20:44:49.266 DEBUG 12555 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.s.c.a.a.b.AuthenticationManagerBuilder : Failed to perform build. Returning null

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A parent AuthenticationManager or a list of AuthenticationProviders is required
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.checkState(ProviderManager.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>(ProviderManager.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder.performBuild(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder.performBuild(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.java:47)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.getOrBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:164)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:280)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:322)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fb023809.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$2(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fb023809$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8b55b724.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fb023809.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:467)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getOrderedBeansOfType(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:267)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:212)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

2013-11-06 20:44:49.408  INFO 12555 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/health'], []
2013-11-06 20:44:49.408  INFO 12555 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/info'], []
2013-11-06 20:44:49.408  INFO 12555 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/css/**'], []
2013-11-06 20:44:49.408  INFO 12555 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/js/**'], []
2013-11-06 20:44:49.408  INFO 12555 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/images/**'], []
2013-11-06 20:44:49.408  INFO 12555 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], []
2013-11-06 20:44:49.408  INFO 12555 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/error'], []
```

I have made no changes to the files at all, outside of running maven to build the Eclipse project (and whatever STS might have done when I imported it).  The site seems to work fine.  I can login using user/password, I can log out.  No errors.  But that stack trace looks bad.  Is this just a red haring message, caused by not-so-production code that may not be 100% ready for mass consumption, or is this indicating some problem that I should be chasing down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace is logged at DEBUG level (and is therefore ignorable). I raised this issue with Rob Winch, and I think he agreed in the end that it's unnecessary to log it at all, so it might not happen when Spring Security 3.2 is GA.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I didn't want to start moving forward with my project using this as a base if it were going to cause problems down the line.